# Same Variable Names - 2 Different Classes - How To Copy Values From One To Another - Reflection - C#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Without using AutoMapper... (because someone in charge of this project will shit bricks when they see dependencies)

I have a class (class A) with however many properties.  I have another class (class B) with those same properties (same names and type). Class B could also have other un related variables.

Is there some simple reflection code that can copy values from class A to class B?

The simpler the better.

Comment: Automaper!! This code is already written for you.

Comment: You could also resort to Fasterflect (http://fasterflect.codeplex.com), which provides object mapping and cloning as services built on dynamic IL generation (but then that would also be a dependency).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
Type typeB = b.GetType();
foreach (PropertyInfo property in a.GetType().GetProperties())
{
    if (!property.CanRead || (property.GetIndexParameters().Length > 0))
        continue;

    PropertyInfo other = typeB.GetProperty(property.Name);
    if ((other != null) && (other.CanWrite))
        other.SetValue(b, property.GetValue(a, null), null);
}
```

Comment: What's up with the superfluous brackets? Also be aware that any reference type properties copied will still point to the original objects.

Comment: @morten im not copying the property itself.  Using SetValue and GetValue to **SET** the value.  So i think it should be okay?  Am i rite?

Comment: @Issa It depends on what behavior you want :) You are setting the property value, but if that value is an object reference then what you are doing corresponds to "var a = new object(); var b = a;". That is, you are copying the reference only and not creating a deep clone of the referenced object.

Comment: @morten the variables are only of type double so I think I will be good. But yea i get your point.  Good looking out.

Answer (score 4):

This?

```
static void Copy(object a, object b)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo propA in a.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        PropertyInfo propB = b.GetType().GetProperty(propA.Name);
        propB.SetValue(b, propA.GetValue(a, null), null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Darn it, you beat me to it. You will have to do this for all members however, not just properties.

Answer (score 1):

If you will use it for more than one object then it may be useful to get mapper:

```
public static Action<TIn, TOut> GetMapper<TIn, TOut>()
{
    var aProperties = typeof(TIn).GetProperties();
    var bType = typeof (TOut);

    var result = from aProperty in aProperties
                 let bProperty = bType.GetProperty(aProperty.Name)
                 where bProperty != null &&
                       aProperty.CanRead &&
                       bProperty.CanWrite
                 select new { 
                              aGetter = aProperty.GetGetMethod(),
                              bSetter = bProperty.GetSetMethod()
                            };

    return (a, b) =>
               {
                   foreach (var properties in result)
                   {
                       var propertyValue = properties.aGetter.Invoke(a, null);
                       properties.bSetter.Invoke(b, new[] { propertyValue });
                   }
               };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you asked for reflection code and It's an old post but I have a different suggestion and wanted to share it. It could be more faster than reflection.

You can serialize the input object to json string, then deserialize to output object. All the properties with same name will assign to new object's properties automatically.

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(a);
var b = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
PropertyInfo[] aProps = typeof(A).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

PropertyInfo[] bProps = typeof(B).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);

    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in aProps)
                {
                    PropertyInfo infoObj = bProps.Where(info => info.Name == pi.Name).First();
                    if (infoObj != null)
                    {
                        infoObj.SetValue(second, pi.GetValue(first, null), null);
                    }
                }
```